# Different output from .map() and .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I cannot for the life of me figure out the difference between these two blocks of code:

```
var text = [];
$(".article-text p").each(function() {
    text.push( $(this).text() );
});
```

And

```
var text = $('.article-text p').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
});
```

They look to me like they produce the same exact output when tested in console on [the following page](http://yaledailynews.com/blog/2002/10/29/mens-water-polo-places-second/). However, the first one can be run by `JSON.stringify`, and the second cannot.

My error message in the crawler says

> Error invoking user-provided 'pageFunction': Error: TypeError: JSON.stringify cannot serialize cyclic structures.

My error message in console says:

> Uncaught DOMException: Blocked a frame with origin "http://yaledailynews.com" from accessing a cross-origin frame.
>       at JSON.stringify ()
>       at :1:6

When I compare the two objects, they look exactly the same, except that the second has a `context` property. I have deleted this property but the errors still remain.

Comment: [`$.map()`](https://api.jquery.com/map/) returns a jQuery object: "_As the return value is a jQuery object, which contains an array, it's very common to call .get() on the result to work with a basic array._"

Comment: When a jQuery method seems to be doing something unexpected, or unanticipated, look at the documentation. It's not perfect, but it's very good and clearly documents what the method does, what arguments it may expect and what it returns.

Comment: @Andreas my bad, you're right :)

Comment: A bit late, but thank you so much! I didn't even know that they were jQuery methods, I am not so great at coding.

Answer (score 2):

From the docs for [jQuery.map](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/)

> Array-like objects — those with a `.length` property and a value on the `.length - 1` index — must be converted to actual arrays before being passed to `$.map()`. The jQuery library provides `$.makeArray()` for such conversions.

Since `$('.article-text p')` will return an array-like collection (of jQuery objects), you must call [$.makeArray](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.makeArray/) on it:

```js
function one() {
  var text = [];
  $(".test").each(function() {
    text.push($(this).text());
  });
  return text;
}

function two() {
  var text = $('.test').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  });
  return text;
}

console.log(one());
// use makeArray here
console.log($.makeArray(two()));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">A</div>
<div class="test">B</div>
<div class="test">C</div>
```

Docs also say

> As the return value is a jQuery object, which contains an array, it's very common to call .get() on the result to work with a basic array.

```js
function one() {
  var text = [];
  $(".test").each(function() {
    text.push($(this).text());
  });
  return text;
}

function two() {
  var text = $('.test').map(function() {
    return $(this).text();
  }).get(); // <--- call get here
  return text;
}

console.log(one());
console.log(two());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test">A</div>
<div class="test">B</div>
<div class="test">C</div>
```